# Python: get text from tkinter scrolledtext and read line by line

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-scrolledtext

I'm currently working on a simple txt converter. The data is loaded from a txt file into a scrolledtext widget. Now I want to read this text line by line (since I'd like to have the opportunity to edit the original data) and do the conversion based on the scrolledtext data. However, I can't get satisfying results.

If I simply print the text I got by using `.get('1.0', 'end-1c')` it looks exactly like the scrolledtext data. Now I want to read it line by line with a `for` loop and seperate it with the `strip` and `split` command. Basically the same way I was doing when reading directly from the file, but it's not working.

Input data contains a lot of spaces:

```
"                  1267    33311225.807"
"                  1268    33311224.395"
```

I would expect ['1267', '33311225.807']. Instead I get a new line for every digit:

```
[1]
[2]
[6]
[8]
...
```

and so on.

```
import tkinter.scrolledtext as tkst
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Converter")
root.geometry('1000x690+200+50')
tab_parent = ttk.Notebook(root)

tab1 = ttk.Frame(tab_parent)
tab_parent.add(tab1, text="  convert  ")

frame1 = tk.Frame(tab1)
textPad_top = tkst.ScrolledText(master=frame1)

coordinates_text = textPad_top.get('1.0', 'end-1c')
for line in coordinates_text:
    line_splitted = line.strip().split(" ")
    read_coordinates = [ele for ele in line_splitted if ele.strip()]
    point_id.append(read_coordinates[0])
    r_value.append(read_coordinates[1])

root.mainloop()
```

Eventually I want to have several lists. One for every column given in the source file.
I'm an absolute beginner in programming and would really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you iterate over a string, it will iterate over each character which is exactly what you're reporting.

If you want to iterate over each line, you need to split the data on newlines

```
for line in coordinates_text.split("\n"):
    ...
```

Comment: Very good to know - that works perfectly fine. Thanks a lot!
But what data type do I have if I open a file and iterate over it? I thought it's also a string.

Comment: @Michael: if you iterate over a file, the data type is an open file. The open file is designed to return one line at a time when you iterate over it.